# replace the last word

Tags: c#, regex

i want to replace the last string as ""..

Eg:-here the string is **apple and mango and**
the output should be **apple and mango**

if the last word is OR, NOT, AND i have to replace that to ""....

Thanks in advance....

Comment: presumably also remove the space in front of it too, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `Regex.Replace` (in `System.Text.RegularExpressions`)

```
Regex.Replace("This is the sentence AND", @"(AND|OR|NOT)\z", "");
```

`\z` is a "end of the string"-anchor

You should also use `string.Trim()` after that to trim excess spaces.

Comment: RegexBuddy is great tool (select the .NET variant from drop-down). There are a lot of "regex designers" out there. Good Luck.

Comment: RegexBuddy cost $. [Regulator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/regulator/ "Regulator") is a great free alternative.

Answer (score 1):

No need for regex:

```
string GetTrimmed(string str, string ending) 
{
  return str.EndsWith(ending) ?
    str.Substring(0, str.Length - ending.Length) :
    str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple regex:

```
/( (and|or|not))$/i
```

Matches a space, followed by 'and', 'or' or 'not', at the end of the string. The `i` after the closing regex marker tells it to be case insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

You can match that word with following regex:

```
.*(\s+(or|not|and)\s*)$
```

Answer (score 0):

You weren't exact about spaces in there, but the following regex should do it:

```
s/ \(and\|or\|not\) *$//gi
```